# How can I use a variable in my reducer, set with an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some issues using one of my variable as an object.

```
import React from 'react'

const PaginationReducer = function(state = {}, action){

 switch(action.type){


    case 'PAGINATION_INIT_REDUCER' :

        console.log('REDUCER RECEIVED ' +  action.payload.currentPage); 
        state[ action.payload.name ] =  action.payload.value;
        state[action.payload.totalPage] = action.payload.totalPage
        state[action.payload.currentPage] = action.payload.currentPage
        return { ...state }
        break;

        case 'PAGINATION_CHANGE' :

        var newPagination = {totalPage : action.payload.totalPage, currentPage:action.payload.currentPage }
        var name= action.payload.paginationName;
        return { ...state, name : newPagination }}
        break;


}

return state;
```

}

export {PaginationReducer}

My probleme is with using name, I cannot find a way to get action.payload.paginationName as my key.

I'm not an expert in Js.

Comment: It's little bit unclear what you exactly need. Please update your question that addresses your issue.

Comment: action.payload.paginationName  will contain a different string according to wich page call the componant pagination.

Comment: Then, @Ricardo answer should satisfy your question.

Comment: Ricardo answer return an undefined as my name

Comment: Show us how you implemented it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get the question. You want to use `action.payload.paginationName` as an object key instead of `name`? If so, You can do this:

```
return {
  ...state,
  [action.payload.paginationName] : newPagination,
}
```

Basically the `[]` lets you use defined variables as keys in objects.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize state with `name` attribute too.

```
const PaginationReducer = function(state = {name:{}, action){
```